# Jquery get this.value from an input field on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the value from an input field when I click the button using jquery? 
Below is my Jquery code :

```
asset_status_list = '';
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/asset_status",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (response) {
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          asset_status_list = '<tr><td >' + response[i].job_card_no + '</td><td >' + response[i].number + '</td><td>' + response[i].type + '</td><td ><input type="text" name="view_more_id" class="view_more_id' + response[i].asset_id + ' btn btn-default" id="view_more_id" value="' + response[i].asset_id + '"/><button id="view_more_link" class="view_more_link' + response[i].asset_id + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in "></i>View More</button></td></tr>';
          $('#asset_status_tr').append(asset_status_list);

          $("#asset_status_tr").on("click", ".view_more_link" + response[i].asset_id, function () {
              console.log(response);
              var asset_id = this.value;
             alert(asset_id);

          });
      }

      $('#asset_table_status').DataTable({});
  },
  error: function (response) {

  }
});
```

I want to get the value of the input field name view_more_id .

Comment: Next time do some research first. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791811/jquery-get-text-input-fields-value-on-button-clicking-event

Comment: What does any of that code have to do with your question? And why is there no relevant code in your question, particularly, things you tried

Comment: @Roope the  link won't help me. I did the research. The problem is the text field has to be unique for each field and it is generated from an autoloop e.g I can have view_more_1 , view_more_2 ,...etc

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Is your click event working??

Comment: Well, what your question clearly asks is what I linked. If that's not what you're asking then please edit your question to include all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer you are looking for ? var asset_id = $( "#view_more_id" ).val();

Comment: No that won't work because we are looping through the text fields.

Comment: Oh ok, so I didn't understand what's the problem you are facing, sorry.