# How to get value of the element after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get value input element after I click on it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupShapes" data-theme="none" style="z-index:999">
        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" style="margin:0; width:250px;">
            <div data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" />
                        <label for="pointToggle">draw point</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" />
                        <label for="lineToggle">draw line</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" />
                        <label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /collapsible -->
        </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
    </div><!-- /popup -->
```

Here is jquery functiot that fired after I click on input element.

```
$("#popupShapes ul li input").click(function (element) {
    var el = $("#" + element.target).val();   
});
```

My question is how to get value of th clicked input?

Comment: `var el = $(this).val();` Also note that you should use the `change` event on radio and checkbox inputs for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery. Get text input field's value on button clicking event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791811/jquery-get-text-input-fields-value-on-button-clicking-event)

Comment: There are sooooooo many duplicates of this question. I'd advise you do some searching before asking next time.

Comment: You're not doing anyone any favours accepting that answer which doesn't resolve the numerous other niggles with your code.   (mine is tagged "community wiki" so I'm not getting rep for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#popupShapes ul li input").click(function (element) {
  //var el = $("#" + element.target).val(); 
  console.log($(this).val()); // will display point, line or polygon appropriately whichever input is clicked.
});
```

Comment: right, so you can call two jQuery functions (  `$(this)` and `.val()` ) to retrieve that value or, you can call _none_:  `this.value`

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to target the current clicked element, like `$(this).val()`:

```js
$("#popupShapes ul li input").click(function(element) {
  var el = $(this).val();
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupShapes" data-theme="none" style="z-index:999">
  <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" style="margin:0; width:250px;">
    <div data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" />
          <label for="pointToggle">draw point</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" />
          <label for="lineToggle">draw line</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" />
          <label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /collapsible -->
  </div>
  <!-- /collapsible set -->
</div>
<!-- /popup -->
```

Comment: @Alnitak, yes, of course, plain JavaScript, there is more than one way...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use "currentTarget.value"

```js
$("#popupShapes ul li input").click(function (element) {
    var el = element.currentTarget.value;  
    console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupShapes" data-theme="none" style="z-index:999">
        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" style="margin:0; width:250px;">
            <div data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" />
                        <label for="pointToggle">draw point</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" />
                        <label for="lineToggle">draw line</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" />
                        <label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /collapsible -->
        </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
    </div><!-- /popup -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a number of suggestions for you (some cribbed from @RoryMcCrossan):

1. for accessibility reasons you should trap the `change` event instead of the `click` event.  Clicking isn't the only way to change an input's state.
2. you don't need to look at `event.target`, jQuery will always pass the element of interest as the `this` context variable (NB: the passed parameter is an `Event` object, not an "element").
3. given that `this` variable, you can access its value directly without using jQuery methods as `this.value`
4. I always recommend using `.on` to register event handlers, because it makes the intent clearer.  The `.click` function (and others in that family) cn be used to both *register* an event handler and *trigger* one, depending on the arguments, meaning that you have to read the function parameters to figure out the intent.
5. There's no other "interesting" elements within `#popupShapes`, so your selector is too specific.

Given this:

```
$("#popupShapes input").on("change", function() {
    var value = this.value; 
    ...
});
```

For further efficiency, you can tell jQuery not to register the event handler on each button directly, but on their container element.  When the radio button selection is changed, the event will *bubble up* through the DOM until an event handler is found.  This is known as *event delegation*.

Putting that altogether you get:

```
$("#popupShapes").on("change", "input", function() {
    var value = this.value; 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need  $(this).val(); in your click event.
Or
In your click method use this to get the value
$(this).attr("value");